# Redactor adding unnecessary tags while editing font families to text in editor

Tags: redactor, redactor.js

I am using redactor 9.2.6 and so far it worked fine. But now I came up with really annoying issues with redactor. I have added a font-family plugin which I found here [Font-Family](http://imperavi.com/redactor/plugins/)

After that when I try to select text inside editor and then change the font family it changes the font but adding up spans every time. For example

[Example Link](http://hf-dev.info/redactor926/index.html)

```
<span style="font-family:abc;">
    <span style="font-family:xyz;">
        <span style="font-family:pqr;">
            Lorem Ipsum
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Whereas it should change the font family in style without adding extra tags. Like

```
<span style="font-family:pqr;"> // font family pqr since it was the one selected last.
   Lorem Ipsum
</span>
```

I tried to contact redactor support as I have purchased this and it seems even they do not know how to fix this. They are ignoring and asking for ways to replicate this issue even I tried to give them every single detail of replicating.

Any one facing this issue or any ways to solve this ??